# Issue setting border in UITableViewCell and flickering when scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have problem setting the top border to `UITableViewCell`. My requirement is to setup the bottom borders for all the cells and only top border to the first cell. I used the below code to setup this

```
if (indexPath.row == 0){
  CALayer* topCellBorder = [CALayer layer];
  topCellBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 1, CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame) , 0.5);
  topCellBorder.backgroundColor = [config getColour:@"theme.table-border.color"].CGColor;
  [cell.layer addSublayer:topCellBorder];
}
CALayer* bottomCellBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomCellBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame) - 0.5, CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame)  , 0.5);
bottomCellBorder.backgroundColor = [config getColour:@"theme.table-border.color"].CGColor;
[cell.layer addSublayer:bottomCellBorder];
```

This works fine at first, heres the screenshot
[image]

But after the scroll, the top border is gone and added to the next view like this

[image]

Also i am seeing the border flickers when scroll. Any ideas what causing this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells are being reused so the old borders remain. When you scroll the first cell will be reused for some other cell and it will already have `topCellBorder`.

I suggest you add cell border in `awakeFromNib` method for the cell and simply toggle on and off top and bottom border. So your cells should have both border layers, but based on `indexPath.row` in table view data source, you just show and hide them.

Comment: thanks @Stefan. Yep  i supected the cell reuse is the issue. But `awakeFromNib` is a good  idea. will try and see